# What's a good name for the part of a URL after the hostname?

Tags: url, naming

I'm parsing a path string containing everything after the hostname, meaning the path, query, and fragment. Previously, I was calling this whole chunk the `path` in a function `parseUrlPath`, but that's a bit confusing, since I'm calling both the inner part and the whole thing the `path`

Maybe it's not the worst idea... I mean, we use the word "server" for both the machine itself and the program running on that machine. But does anyone have an idea? Or even better, a reference citing an existing name for the path/query/fragment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js) calls the function `path()` for getting/setting the path and `resource()` for setting the part of the URI "comprising of path, query, and fragment."

Given the URI `https://user@example.com:8080/foo/bar.html?q=3#baz`:

```
path() === '/foo/bar.html'
query() === 'q=3'
resource() === '/foo/bar.html?q=3#baz'
```

This might be useful: https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html

Comment: Resource is a good one too! Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I kept saying "relative to the domain" to myself without realizing that was the answer.

A good name for such a function would be `parseHostnameRelativeUrl` or simply `parseRelativeUrl` if it's understood that the hostname is what we are always relative to.

Source for idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005174/2407870

* Technically, it would be `parseAuthorityRelativeUrl`, since the "authority" part includes from the user info up to the path, but no one would understand that.

Answer (score 0):

The well-known parts are: protocol, hostname (service name + second-level domain name + top-level domain name), directory name or major category, sub-directory or sub category, filename, file extension, and finally followed by parameters. Only the protocol and hostname are mandatory though modern apps may provide defaults or search engine lookups when something's missing.